# set focus on ListBox mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, focus

I have a ListBox populated with values, a Grid with a couple of TextBox and
a Button. 
When an element is selected in the ListBox, the corresponding values ​​fill the TextBox in the Grid.
The Button is used to clean the TextBox.
So, my problem is: when I use the Button to clean the TextBox, the element
in the ListBox is still selected.
How can I 'deselect' that element?
Do I need to reset the focus of the ListBox?
If it is the case, is it possible to do it without writing code in the code-behind?

Thanks a lot.

Here is the code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="intTrainningID"
    SelectedValuePath="intTrainningID">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
              <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ListBoxCommand}"
                   MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True" 
                   PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>

<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25px"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25px"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="TrainningID:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TrainningID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <Label Content="DateCreated:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" SelectedDate="{Binding DateCreated, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <ToolBarPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Clean" Command="{Binding CleanCommand}" CommandParameter="All Cleaned" />
    </Menu>
    </ToolBarPanel>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is:

Bind the listbox SelectedValue to a property in your MVVM, and Set listbox selectedValue to null inside the CleanCommand.

first define the property in your mvvm:

```
private YourType _selectedListBoxValue;
public YourType SelectedListBoxValue
{
    get { return _selectedListBoxValue; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedListBoxValue!= value)
        {
            _selectedListBoxValue= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedListBoxValue");
        }
    }
}
```

Then bind in your listbox xaml:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedListBoxValue}"
```

And finally use the CleanCommand to set the SelectedListBoxValue to null.

```
private void OnCleanCommand(){
SelectedListBoxValue = null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but this solution does not work. After making the call to OnCleanCommand() the register in the listBox is still selected.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to change the SelectedListBoxValue type from string to the relevant type that you are using, if it doesnt do the trick than please post your full code? I'll take a look and verify it on my end. (edited my answer)

Comment: Hi, I added the same code that you posted earlier: the new property and the SelectedListBoxValue = null in the viewmodel, and the bind in the xaml. In the property I used OnPropertyChanged(..) instead of RaisePropertyChanged(..). Thanks

Comment: I got a clue: in the ListBox in xaml there is another binding: ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems, Mode=TwoWay}" used to fill the ListBox with values. So, after the execution of the OnCleanCommand, the app execute that bind (AllItem) and refill the ListBox. I think this is not correct.

Comment: As I pointed out before you need to change the SelectedListBoxValue type to T_Trainning. Anyway I had put together a working solution for you. here is a link: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6837746_80955217_417231

Answer (score 0):

I repost the entire code in order to make it clearer.

xaml:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="strDescription"
    SelectedValuePath="intTrainningID"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedListBoxValue}">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ListBoxCommand}"
                MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True" 
                PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>

<ToolBarPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Clean" Command="{Binding CleanCommand}" CommandParameter="All Cleaned" />
    </Menu>
</ToolBarPanel>
```

viewmodel:

```
public MainWidowViewModel(MainWindow pView)
    {
        ..
        CleanCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(CleanAllItems));
        ..
    }

private List<T_Trainning> _allItems;
public List<T_Trainning> AllItems
{
    get
    {
        if (_allItems == null)
            _allItems = LoadItems();
        return _allItems;
    }
    private set
    {
        _allItems = value;
    }
}

private string _selectedListBoxValue;
public string SelectedListBoxValue
{
    get { return _selectedListBoxValue; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedListBoxValue != value)
        {
            _selectedListBoxValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedListBoxValue");    
        }
    }
}

public void CleanAllItems(object obj)
{
    ..
    SelectedListBoxValue = null;
    ..
}

void LBItemSelected(object obj)
{
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e = (SelectionChangedEventArgs)obj;
    T_Trainning tra = (T_Trainning)e.AddedItems[0];
    TrainningID = tra.intTrainningID.Value;
    ..
}
```